# error using netbeans 7.3 IDE exit value 1

Tags: performance, netbeans-7

> AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x715B0000, RegionSize 0x150000, State
>   0x10000 C:\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for
>   cygwin's heap, Win32 error 487
>
> BUILD FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 94ms)

It's a NetBeans 7.3.1 IDE.

Comment: Seems like a memory allocation problem, but could you provide some context? When does this error occurs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild the binary or if that doesn't help you can also try to create the project from scratch and check if that helps